# Fatal error: no such file or directory

Tags: c++

I have downloaded the source code to do some benchmark for couple of C++ library. I don't have much knowledge in C++. I downloaded the libraries. When I try to compile the code

```
g++ test_matrix_pseudoinverse.cpp -o test_matrix_pseudoinverse
```

I get this error

> test_matrix_pseudoinverse.cpp:26:64: fatal error:
>   opencv2.4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or
>   directory  #include
>   
>                                                                   ^ compilation terminated.

The source code with all the libraries are in github

https://github.com/shiblybcc/linear-algebra-benchmark

I have downloaded the code from [here](http://nghiaho.com/?p=1726). It would be nice if someone could tell me why I am getting this error and how to run the code without any error.

I am on linux and I have added opencv2 folder in /usr/local/include directory.

Comment: You need to have the OpenCV source installed at the location it expects i.e. `opencv2.4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/`. Is that the case?

Comment: I already added the OpenCV

Comment: When specifying absolute paths, use quotes instead of brackets.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp -- There are no #include directives in `test_matrix_pseudoinverse.cpp` that use an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is resulted from not setting the include path if the file complained by the compiler does exist. Suppose your OpenCV source code tree is under /home/yourhome (i.e the full path to the file reported not existed should be /home/yourhome/opencv2.4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp), you need to specify the include path by `-I/home/yourhome` argument. Therefore the full command line to build should be as:
`g++ -I/home/yourhome test_matrix_pseudoinverse.cpp -o test_matrix_pseudoinverse`

Comment: have you tried to run the code? This is not working for me. I get this error `undefined reference to `cv::operator*(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&)'`

Comment: @user1670773: it sounds like the include now works and compilation succeeded, but linking failed. You need to link the built libraries also. See stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2132213

Comment: Yes, as addressed by Kundor, the original issue looks solved while the second issue is in fact another new issue - the linking issue. For your linking issue, you need to check if your downloaded OpenCV has library built or not. If it was, you need to specify link options "-L _the_path_to_your_opencv_library_" and "-lthe_library_name". If not, build it first. Usually the library itself should have ".a" or ".lib" postfix. Suppose the library is at "/home/yourhome/opencv2.4/lib/" and its name is "libopencv.a", you can specify your g++ linking options as "-L/home/yourhome/opencv2.4/lib -lopencv".

Comment: @user1670773 You can't run code that doesn't compile or link.