# How to remove the error: pcl/memory.h: No such file or directory while building c++ file?

Tags: c++, cmake, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to make [this tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pairwise_incremental_registration.php) work for Various Point Cloud of Faces.

I did found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633207/pcl-pcl-config-h-no-such-file-or-directory) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725246/fatal-error-no-such-file-or-directory) answer, but can't seem to make them work for my case.

I am trying to execute the "CMake" and "Make" command to build the C++ files.

I have already run this [Correspondence Grouping tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php) succesfully.
Please help I am a beginner in Point Cloud Computations.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Here is a snip of my error specifically:

```
Scanning dependencies of target pairwise_incremental_registration
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o
/home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp:41:10: fatal error: pcl/memory.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcl/memory.h>  // for pcl::make_shared
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2 FATAL_ERROR)

project(tuto-pairwise)

find_package(PCL 1.4 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (pairwise_incremental_registration pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp)
target_link_libraries (pairwise_incremental_registration ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

My Makefile generated is:-

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.10

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No interactive CMake dialog available..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -E echo No\ interactive\ CMake\ dialog\ available.
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build/CMakeFiles /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named pairwise_incremental_registration

# Build rule for target.
pairwise_incremental_registration: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 pairwise_incremental_registration
.PHONY : pairwise_incremental_registration

# fast build rule for target.
pairwise_incremental_registration/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build
.PHONY : pairwise_incremental_registration/fast

pairwise_incremental_registration.o: pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o

.PHONY : pairwise_incremental_registration.o

# target to build an object file
pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o
.PHONY : pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o

pairwise_incremental_registration.i: pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.i

.PHONY : pairwise_incremental_registration.i

# target to preprocess a source file
pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.i
.PHONY : pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.i

pairwise_incremental_registration.s: pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.s

.PHONY : pairwise_incremental_registration.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.s
.PHONY : pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... pairwise_incremental_registration"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... pairwise_incremental_registration.o"
    @echo "... pairwise_incremental_registration.i"
    @echo "... pairwise_incremental_registration.s"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

After VERBOSE=1, the output of make

```
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds -

B/home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build/CMakeFiles /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build'
    make -f CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/depend
    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build'
    cd /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build/CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build'
    make -f CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build
    make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build'
    [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o
    /usr/bin/c++  -DDISABLE_DAVIDSDK -DDISABLE_DSSDK -DDISABLE_ENSENSO -DDISABLE_LIBUSB_1_0 -DDISABLE_PCAP -DDISABLE_PNG -DDISABLE_RSSDK -DFLANN_STATIC -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -Dqh_QHpointer -DvtkFiltersFlowPaths_AUTOINIT="1(vtkFiltersParallelFlowPaths)" -DvtkIOExodus_AUTOINIT="1(vtkIOParallelExodus)" -DvtkIOGeometry_AUTOINIT="1(vtkIOMPIParallel)" -DvtkIOImage_AUTOINIT="1(vtkIOMPIImage)" -DvtkIOParallel_AUTOINIT="1(vtkIOMPIParallel)" -DvtkIOSQL_AUTOINIT="2(vtkIOMySQL,vtkIOPostgreSQL)" -DvtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT="1(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL)" -DvtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT="3(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingOpenGL)" -DvtkRenderingFreeType_AUTOINIT="2(vtkRenderingFreeTypeFontConfig,vtkRenderingMatplotlib)" -DvtkRenderingLIC_AUTOINIT="1(vtkRenderingParallelLIC)" -DvtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT="1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL)" -I/usr/include/vtk-6.3 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/hdf5/openmpi -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/jsoncpp -I/usr/include/tcl -I/usr/include/pcl-1.8 -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/usr/include/ni -I/usr/include/openni2 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++  -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o -c /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp
    /home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp:41:10: fatal error: pcl/memory.h: No such file or directory
     #include <pcl/memory.h>  // for pcl::make_shared
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build'
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sparsh/Desktop/incremental_pair_clouds/build'
    Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Stuff present in /usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl

```
/usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl$ ls

2d                for_each_type.h      outofcore         point_cloud.h             ros
apps              geometry             pcl_base.h        PointIndices.h            sample_consensus
cloud_iterator.h  impl                 pcl_config.h      point_representation.h    search
common            in_hand_scanner      pcl_exports.h     point_traits.h            segmentation
compression       io                   PCLHeader.h       point_types_conversion.h  sse.h
console           kdtree               PCLImage.h        point_types.h             stereo
conversions.h     keypoints            pcl_macros.h      PolygonMesh.h             surface
correspondence.h  ml                   PCLPointCloud2.h  range_image               TextureMesh.h
exceptions.h      ModelCoefficients.h  PCLPointField.h   recognition               tracking
features          modeler              pcl_tests.h       register_point_struct.h   Vertices.h
filters           octree               people            registration              visualization
```

Comment: The PCL includes are missing. You did not link to the PCL library. Can you show us the CMakeLists.txt you are using? I did not find them in the links you provided.

Comment: @vre Hi, I have updated the question with the CMakeLists.txt file, though I had used the tutorial's CMakeLists with "cmake" version changed (First line of CMakelists.txt) according to the version in my machine.

Comment: You can inspect the generated Makefile to make sure the specified include directories are correct.

Comment: @JohnFilleau So I did scrutinize the Makefile and compared it with some other generated files, so it looked fine to me. But I am a beginner and I am not very well versed with CMake files, so I might be wrong. For your kind perusal I have updated the answer with my Makefile.

Comment: Looks like you need to check out this file now `pairwise_incremental_registration.dir/build.make`. I think you can pass VERBOSE=1 to your make command and it should show you which include directory you have. You could also add `message("PCL Include Directory: ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")` to your `CMakelists.txt` after `find_package` to see what value this has. There's a couple of ways you can find out.

Comment: I have mentioned output after mentioning
message("PCL Include Directory: ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
after find_package and also using VERBOSE=1. 
Please give your opinion after this..

Comment: Is there `/usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/memory.h` file? Is there anything in `/usr/include/pcl-1.8` dir? Whoa, is `PCL_FOUND` set? Maybe add `REQUIRED` to `find_package`. Maybe change the pcl version from 1.4 to 1.8, you seem to use 1.8 anyway.

Comment: @KamilCuk Oh yeah! their is no memory.h in pcl. I have added the stuff inside pcl-1.8/pcl/ in question.

Comment: I see the `memory.h` file [is very freshly new](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/commits/master/common/include/pcl/memory.h). Could be your installation of pcl is old enough so that it does not have the file. I would.. "fear" adding a single file, that never works, libraries have inter-file dependencies (like the commit that introduced the file, moved somethings around). If you wish to use the newest version of some library, I would rather consider just remove the currently installed library and installing the library from [sources](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl).

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial has been updated for the latest PCL version which is 1.10 as of now.
`<pcl/memory.h>` is not part of PCL 1.8.
Use this older version of the [example](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/0c626b1e9f352cfbcf3694773667e5daae4f1502/doc/tutorials/content/sources/pairwise_incremental_registration/pairwise_incremental_registration.cpp) which is compatible with 1.8.